# Оглушается ли частица "б"?

Tags: фонетика, орфоэпия

В сослагательном наклонении используют частицы "бы" и её вариант "б". По поводу последней у меня и вопрос: Оглушается ли частица "б" в устной речи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Коль скоро приведены "смущающие" примеры использования, то брошу свои пять копеек.
Частица в редуцированной форме, разумеется, оглушается в зависимости от последующего звука. Но вся штука в том, что в подобных позициях - после глаголов - редуцированную форму можно найти разве что в стихах, поскольку  частица обычно находится под логическим ударением и потому выступает в полной форме. Это первое. 
И второе. Вне зависимости от всего сказанного, я не уверен, что это редуцированная форма всегда произносится именно как редуцированная до одного согласного. Может, у кого-то там сохраняется сверхкраткий гласный (т.н. шва). Но это уже вне орфоэпических норм, нормативно, повторюсь, позиционное оглушение.

Answer (score 2):

Конечно, оглушается, ведь она не произносится отдельно, а обычно "прилипает" к предыдущему слову:если б (йэслип), что б (штоп), а на конце слов парные звонкие оглушаются

Comment: Меня смущает скорее после глаголов *сидел б, говорил б* и т. п.

Comment: В таких случаях все зависит от позиции: сидел б ты (сиделп ты), сидел б на месте (сиделб на месте)

Comment: Неужели так говорят?